# Windows won't boot after installing Ubuntu 18.04 (Boots to Recovery screen)

Tags: grub2, windows, 18.04

Windows boots fine from Ubuntu 17 grub, but Ubuntu 18 grub it just shows the Windows "Recovery" blue screen

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of kicking myself. The exact same day I installed Ubuntu 18.04, my hard drive power cable got internally loose (the SATA cable was fine)

I found this out by booting into Ubuntu, opening Nautilus, going to "Other Locations" and noticing the Windows hard drive *was not showing up*. So then I got curious, because I KNEW it *SHOULD* show up.

So I cracked open the computer with a headlamp and noticed the cabling to the hard drive seemed wrong. I plugged it back in WHILE Nautilus was running and it just "popped up"!

Then I just rebooted and grub launched windows just fine. Crazy coincidence